# IOS Framework with push notifications

Tags: ios, sdk, frameworks, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am developing an IOS Framework with several functionalities, and I would like to add push notification services. I created my own push notification service using [Easy APNS](http://www.easyapns.com/). I do not know how to deal with others apps when They integrated my SDK. I mean, I do not know, if they have to send me their distribution certificates, and I can add them in my push notifications service, or If I need to integrate something in their push notification servie.

I do not know how to deal with a Framework that will work with others app and push notifications.

Comment: this is a question for server side implementation rather than ios client side.

Comment: how can i deal with the server side with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, If a app supports **APNS** then it has bundled with **APNS** enabled service(Push Notification service) certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your server is responsible for sending push notifications to all the applications using your SDK, you'll need to get from the developers of those app their push certificates.

I'm assuming that your SDK will handle the sending of the device token from an application to your server. You'll have to know in your server which device token belongs to which application.

For each application for which you wish to send push notifications, you'll have to maintain a separate connection to APNS using the certificate supplied by the developer of that application.