# ios registerForRemoteNotifications in Framework with a different app delegate

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm writing an iOS framework that uses **remote notifications** and would like to be able to distribute the framework to other developers and not require them to implement any of the related app delegate methods. Is that possible?

A similar question was asked here, but it doesn't cover my app delegate issue: [IOS Framework with push notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23054463/ios-framework-with-push-notifications)

I tried to temporarily change the app delegate as described here: [Possible to change AppDelegate at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28464515/possible-to-change-appdelegate-at-runtime)

For example:

```
id<UIApplicationDelegate> originalDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate = self;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate = originalDelegate;
```

But this code crashes the app. (Do I need to implement some required protocol methods?)

The alternative is for the "main app" to receive and pass my remote notifications to my framework. Is there a framework "API" best practice for how to do that?

Thanks!